# How to Choose a Sample for Multiply Classifiers

Tags: python, text-mining, random-forest, sampling

I've got a dataset of 1.5 million and am looking to train 7 different classifiers -- for each classifier I have up to 10 classes to predict. The total sample has 20K text features (more if I include bigrams). Like most distributions of text features, only 20% of them account for 80% of occurrences in the sample. I am going to manually label 10K for each prediction category, and use that to predict against the remaining 1.5 million as well as new documents that come through.

My question is, how would I choose the subsample based on the features and distribution. Should I just choose a random sample (ie try to match the distribution)? Or should I try to find the 10K that maximizes the number of features represented in the sample? Whats the benefit and drawback of each?

I have only one shot to label these 10K so I want to make sure I choose the right sample that maximizes my accuracy for each of the prediction categories!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'll end up with a dataset where each class is fairly represented, with enough data for each class to enable suitable predictive performance. As you currently have no labels, any kind of stratified sampling is unavailable to you.

**Random sampling** will get you the 10K samples you need, but there's no guarantee you'll get fair representation for each of your classes. Assuming you were to use this approach it would make sense to continue to label the samples until you have decent representation for all classes. There is no guarantee regarding balance and also no guarantee that it will cover the majority of the variance of your dataset in feature space either.

**An alternative sampling approach** that is able to capture a majority of the variance of the data in feature space should hold up with better performance/generalisation. There are a few variations of how this could be done but you could try a clustering approach.

Cluster your points in feature space and then instead of sampling randomly, sample from each cluster in turn. So draw a random point from the first cluster, then second, then third etc until the last cluster, and repeat if necessary. Label them in this order and keep an eye on the counts for each class as there is always the chance a class is not well represented by this approach. Another potential drawback in this approach is selecting the number of clusters. You could aim for the number of classes in the dataset or go with anything up to 10K clusters.

An additional variant on this would be the strategy for selecting a sample from the clusters: instead of choosing a random point, choose the sample closest to the centroid; or if choosing multiple points from a cluster, order the samples via distance from centroid and sample uniformly from this.

**Active learning** is a semi-supverised approach that may be the most useful choice in this instance. When labelling, once you've got some decent coverage for each of your classes try an active learning approach to selecting which samples to label next.

Comment: thanks! this is super helpful! I think the active learning approach looks most promising. ill take a look to see how I can implement something like this-- if you are familiar with any resources on this, let me know.